# How can I install new npm dependency (Helmet e.g.) in the deployed Node.js Express project in Digital Ocean

Tags: node.js, express, npm, node-modules, digital-ocean

When I open the terminal and get access to the root folder of the deployed project, is there to install a new npm package like Helmet inside that deployed Node.js Express project?
The app is running on Digital Ocean.

Comment: Why doesn't `npm install helmet` work for you in this scenario? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I didn't try it afraid of crashing the app. I am accessing deployed Node.js files through the Bitwise. So what  I am trying to do is installing it instantly in the deployed project and through the BitWise just add that middleware inside the server.js. So will npm install helmet in the root folder work?
And is there any flag needed like --production or something else?

Comment: No, not as far as I know. `npm install helmet` is just going to add it to the `node_modules` folder, then you'll need to update your code (which you can also do live as long as you aren't doing something like using `nodemon` in production) and then restart your server and the code change will take effect. I'm not familiar with BitWise so you'll have to take that into account with what I've said.